# Training Methodology of CNN in theano with large scale data

Tags: theano, conv-neural-network, training-data, large-data

I am training a CNN with 1M images with theano. Now I am puzzled on how to prepare the training data.

My questions are:

1. When the images resize to 64*64*3, the size of whole data is about 100G. Should I save the data into a single npy file or some smaller files? which one is efficient?
2. How to decide the number of parameters of the CNN? How about 1M/10 = 100K?
3. Should I limit the memory cost of a training block and the CNN parameters less than GPU memory?

My computer is with 16G memory and GPU Titian.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a NN framework like pylearn2, lasagne, Keras, etc, check the docs to see if there are guidelines for iterating batches off disk from an hdf5 store or similar.

If there's nothing and you don't want to roll your own, the [fuel package](https://github.com/mila-udem/fuel) provides lots of helpful data iteration schemes that can be adapted to models in theano (and probably most of the frameworks; there's a good tutorial in the fuel repository).

As for the parameters, you'll have to cross validate to figure out the best parameters for your data.

And yes, the model size + minibatch size + dropout mask for the batch has to be under the available vram.